# Flutter keyboard pops up on an unwanted screen, because a different screen is initialized at the same time in a list

Tags: flutter, dart

I know how to manually make the keyboard go away but that's now what I want, let me explain:

I have a BottomNavigationBar using which I can switch between 5 screens.

This is the code for the body:

```
body: GetBuilder<MainTabBarController>(builder: (_) {
        return IndexedStack(
          index: controller.pageIndex,
          children: controller.tabPages,
        );
      }),
```

This is tabPages in the GetxController:

```
List<Widget> tabPages = [
    HomeScreen(),
    SearchScreen(),
    const Placeholder(color: Colors.orange),
    const Placeholder(color: Colors.green),
    const Placeholder(color: Colors.indigo),
  ];
```

Now the thing is, my SearchScreen has a textfield with autofocus set to true, so that whenever I open the SearchScreen, the keyboard should popup automatically. But the problem that I am having here is that, as soon as the "tabPages" is initializes (which happens after the login as I come to the `MainTabBarScreen()` ), the SearchScreen also gets initialized and it brings up the keyboard even though I am only on the HomeScreen.

I hope I properly explained the issue here, let me know if anymore information is needed. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed the `autofocus: true` from the search-textfield and I added a focusNode to it which only gives the focus to the textfield once I select the search-screen from the bottom-navigation-bar

Answer (score 0):

The following code helped me to hide the keyboard.

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    FocusManager.instance.primaryFocus?.unfocus();
    super.initState();
  }
```

Unfocused from current focus so that keyboard will dismiss.

You enter the above code in other screens except for `SearchScreen()`.

#### Extra

```
GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        
        FocusScopeNode currentfocus = FocusScope.of(context);
       
        if (!currentfocus.hasPrimaryFocus &&
            currentfocus.focusedChild != null) {
         
          FocusManager.instance.primaryFocus?.unfocus();
        }
      },
      child: MaterialApp(),
    )
```

**Warp the `MaterialApp` with `GestureDetector` and enter the above code**

I hope your problem will be solved. Thank you!

Comment: I tried a solution very similar to yours, this has a problem though. The keyboard still appears for a split second and then goes away which results in a bad UX and I don't want that.